# Why is an entity being automatically saved without calling persist when using foreign generation strategy in bidirectional one-to-one mapping?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have been practicing one-to-one mapping in hibernate and don't understand this particular case. I have to say, the program is working fine and as I intended, but apparently I can omit a perist() call and it still works smoothly. The fact that it's working is good, but I want to know exactly why the call is optional. Let me write some details:

This is the user class, which is supposed to be the owning side of the mapping:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @OneToOne
    private Ticket ticket;
    
    public User() {}
    
    public User(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

And this is the ticket class that's supposed to be the dependent one:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Ticket {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="foreignGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(name="foreignGenerator", strategy="foreign", 
    parameters=@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name="property", value="user"))
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy="ticket")       
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;
    
    public Ticket() {
        
    }
    
    public Ticket(User user) {
        this.user=user;
    }   

}
```

I am trying to test the "shared primary key" strategy in one-to-one mapping. As you can see I have set up the generator with foreign strategy, which is supposed to make Ticket's id the same as it's corresponding User's id.

```
    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner loadData() {
        return args->{
            EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            User user=new User("Test User");
            Ticket ticket=new Ticket(user);
            //em.persist(user);
            user.setTicket(ticket);
            em.persist(ticket);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
            //We don't have to call persist on user
        };
    }       
}
```

This program runs perfectly. Uncommenting the line which calls persist on user makes no difference. I am assuming that persisting ticket, which has it's user property set, automatically saves the user as well. Therefore, the reason it makes no difference is that no matter if user is getting saved or not, it will get persisted when we call ticket.

I want to know if my assumption is correct and any additional links to articles/documentation would be greatly appreaciated. Especially I am wondering about this part that I said above-"I am assuming that persisting ticket, which has it's user property set, automatically saves the user as well." I couldn't find anything that would confirm or deny this. I know that the "shared primary key" approach in one-to-one mapping is the only use case of "foreign" generation strategy, so there are not a lot of posts about it, and whatever posts are there are getting overshadowed by "foreign key" during the search.

Any help regarding this or any other issue that might be wrong with the code provided above would be appreciated. Thanks for taking your time to read this

Comment: You should not have the "@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn" annotation on your mapping in Ticket. Mapped by already means the 'target' controls the relationship and that it points to this entities primary key without putting that annotation in there to muddy the waters. It was used in JPA 1.0 for what is now done through derived IDs  and MapsId. I'm actually unclear how this works for you - you are specifying Ticket's ID sequence should be pulled from the User and set as if it is a foreign key, yet User should have a foreign key to ticket "TICKET_ID".

Answer (score 0):

The JPA specification states this behavior is wrong:

Looking at the 3.0 release:
section "3.2.2. Persisting an Entity Instance" implies user is unmanaged after your persist (you can check with the em.contains method).

Section "3.2.4. Synchronization to the Database" covers the flush/commit which states:

```
• If X is a managed entity, it is synchronized to the database.
  ..
  ◦ For any entity Y referenced by a relationship from X, where the relationship to Y has not been annotated with the cascade element value cascade=PERSIST or cascade=ALL:
    ▪ If Y is new or removed, an IllegalStateException will be thrown by the flush operation (and the transaction marked for rollback) or the transaction commit will fail.
```

User is new, so this should be resulting in an exception. That it works might be a glitch in how Hibernate is handling the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation (speculation on my part) and custom "foreignGenerator".

This is not a pattern I'd suggest you rely on, and should instead call persist to avoid inconsistencies with the behavior on other mapping setups.